# package-install reports "no match"

Tags: package

From the [Emacs Eclim](https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim) github page:

> Install emacs-eclim. You have two options:
>
> - Installation from the MELPA package archive.
>
>   Just add the archive to package-archives if you
>   haven't already, and
>
>   then install emacs-eclim with the package-install
>   command.
> - Manual installation from GitHub.
>
>   (git clone git://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim.git)
>
>   Add (add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/emacs-eclim/") to your
>   startup script.

If followed the first option and:

1. Added the following package-archives to my `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file:

   ```
   (setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                            ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                            ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))
   ```
2. Then typed <kbd>M-x</kbd>`package-install` and hit <kbd>RET</kbd> and the following message poped up:

   `Install package: emacs-eclim [No Match]`

---

Why does this error pop up?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe refreshing package contents could help: try evaluating `(package-refresh-contents)` or typing <kbd>M-x</kbd>`package-refresh-contents`.

Comment: How to do evaluating (package-refresh-contents)?

Comment: Just type ```(package-refresh-contents)``` in the ```*scratch*``` buffer and, after the closing bracket, hit ```C-j```.

Comment: The default binding for evaluating is `C-x C-e`.

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to add my experience.  I installed Emacs on my Mac via Homebrew and couldn't get it to find or list any packages from repositories other than the standard GNU ELPA, despite adding MELPA and MELPA Stable to my `package-archives` in my init.el (similar to above), and despite doing `package-refresh-contents`, restarting Emacs, rebooting my machine, etc.

I noticed status messages about using TLS as it was loading `list-packages` (although they all appeared to be successful), and checked my Homebrew Emacs install -- I hadn't installed with the `with-gnutls` option.  I uninstalled Emacs and reinstalled, this time using `with-gnutls`, and this fixed the problem for me.  So, for me, something like:

```
brew install emacs --with-cocoa --with-gnutls
```

Comment: It turns out (perhaps unsurprisingly) that TLS is only required if you use the "https" version of the repository URL's, e.g., if you use `("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")` you need TLS, but if you use `("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")`, which also works, you don't.

Answer (score 1):

To my experience, this failed to detect (and autocomplete) the package I wanted, given a correct setup if you have already installed the package. A way to check that your configuration is properly set up and working is to `package-list-packages` and manually search for the package you want to install.