# "no match" error after `M-x package-install` on a package

Tags: package

I want to install https://github.com/syohex/emacs-helm-gtags, and here is the installation instruction:

> helm-gtags is available on MELPA and MELPA stable
>
> You can install helm-gtags with the following command.
>
> ```
> M-x package-install [RET] helm-gtags [RET]
> ```

But after `M-x package-install [RET] helm-gtags [RET]`, I got "no match".

How shall I solve this problem? Thanks.

---

update:

1) Running `M-x package-refresh-contents [RET]` will stay at "Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80" forever, so doesn't seem to solve the problem. Why doesn't finish running?

2) Even without waiting for "Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80"  to go away, running `package-install` on `helm-gtags` still results in "no match".

3) Do I need to add the repository of `helm-gtags` somewhere, and what is its repository?

Answer (score 9):

`helm-gtags` is not available in [elpa](http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/) repository. You should add `melpa` repository to your packages archives to install `helm-gtags`. Add the following code in your emacs init file,

```
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                     ("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/")))
```

Then press `C-x C-s` to save and `M-x eval-buffer` for the changes to apply. Then try to refresh packages and search for `helm-gtags` package. More information about emacs packages repository can be found in [Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ELPA).

Comment: I get certificate warnings when naively copy/pasting this solution. ("The TLS connection to marmalade-repo.org:443 is insecure for the following reason: certificate has expired") The Marmalade project seems to be defunct. https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MarmaladeRepo

Answer (score 3):

`M-x package-refresh-contents [RET] M-x package-install [RET] helm-gtags [RET]`

Or

`M-x package-list-packages [RET] C-s helm-gtags [RET] i x`

Comment: You might want to elaborate a bit. Explain what the `no match` error means and what your answer does that takes care of it.

Comment: 1) Running `-x package-refresh-contents [RET] ` will stay at "Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80" forever, so doesn't seem to solve the problem. Why doesn't finish running? 2) Even without waiting for "Contacting host: elpa.gnu.org:80"  to go away, running `package-install` on `helm-gtags` still results in "no match". 3) Do I need to add the repository of `helm-gtags` somewhere, and what is its repository?

Comment: If refresh doesn't help, one workaround is to exchange the https repository URL for http, as seen in this comment:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/package-install-reports-no-match?rq=1#comment52676_33083