package-install RET doom-themes RET no match
I want to install a theme library, the package is already installed but emacs does not recognize it. I have already installed the melpa packages and the gnu packages, as shown in the code below:
(add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(setq package-archives '(("gnu" . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
                         ("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/")
                         ("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")))


This started happening today, I already researched and didn't find solutions, just a post on stackoverflow which is where I got this code above, I'm new to emacs, I'm still learning how to use it so I have no idea how I can solve it.
The error message says: package-install RET doom-themes RET no match. What can I try to resolve this error?

If you setq, you clobber the old value of the variable with the new value, so the second line completely obliterates what the first line did. The code you got is probably wrong: where did you get it?

@NickD I got it from stackoverflow in an old post

Link to the post please?

See https://melpa.org/#/getting-started for instructions and don't muck around with setting package-archives: add to the existing value as shown in the instructions.

@NickD https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2490/package-install-reports-no-match

And, thanks again for your help @NickD

You copied the setq from the question of somebody who was asking because he had a problem: that's not a good strategy. Moreover the question is from 10 years ago, and things change. Use the directions I pointed you to.

What you call an error message doesn't look like an Emacs error message. It looks like a minibuffer message shown during completion. Maybe edit your question to say just how/when you see such a message, IOW, a recipe to repro it. Thx.
